# how to plot two stacked bar graph in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I had two stacked bar graphs, one for input another for output.

however i want to plot these two graphs in one space.

I attached the sample.

Please help me!! thank you!!

```
gr_out <- read.csv("graph_out.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
gr_out.metlt<-melt(gr_out)
head(gr_out.metlt)
gr_out.metlt$DMU.Name <- factor(gr_out.metlt$DMU.Name, levels = gr_out$DMU.Name)
q <- ggplot(gr_out.metlt, aes(x = DMU.Name, y = value),add=TRUE)
q + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1),panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+ 
  ylab("Cummulative ratio") + xlab("Station") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")

##graph
gr_in <- read.csv("graph_in.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",")
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
gr_in.metlt<-melt(gr_in)
head(gr_in.metlt)
gr_in.metlt$DMU.Name <- factor(gr_in.metlt$DMU.Name, levels = gr_in$DMU.Name)
p <- ggplot(gr_in.metlt, aes(x = DMU.Name, y = value))
p + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1),panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+ 
  ylim(c(0.0, 8.0)) + ylab("Cummulative ratio") + xlab("Station")+ scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired")
```

This is what I want to achieve
  [image: This is what I want to achieve]

Comment: Can you supply the data or make the example reproducible?

Comment: We can only help so much without the data. My guess is that you want to `rbind()` your two melted data frames together, and assign a tag for the "in" data and the "out" data (do this before you `rbind`). From there you'll use `geom_bar(position="dodge")` or maybe an `interaction` with the data source and category tags to get the desired result.